# Errors after opening new project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just opened a new project in android studio, and it's filled with errors, which, of course, I did not write - therefore, I have no idea what's wrong.

I am using the fullscreen activity option.

It goes like this - the usual thing:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
```

It cannot find the "R" thing, and gets even madder when I try to import the package, and then gives error on the "fullscreen_content" and "activity_main"

Sorry if this has been asked before, I'm a bit clueless, specially when I did nothing yet.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of Android Studio?

Comment: Check your SDK path in File > Project Structure > Android SDK .

Comment: 0.3.2. the new one didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Build` -> `Rebuild Project`
 
Also you can use console:

```
gradlew clean
gradlew assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you must be sure to have:

```
import android.R;
```

where is necessary, but if it doesn´t work, try:

Go to **File -> Settings -> Compiler** now check **`use external build`**

finally, Rebuild your project

Comment: Well, I have imported earlier the android.R, it still doesn't work. 
And it seems as if I don't have this setting in the Compiler Settings... 

thanks :)